# Normalization and RidgeCV in Sklearn Pipeline - possible data leakage?

Tags: scikit-learn, standardization, ridge-regression, data-leakage

To avoid data leakage between the train and test set, I'm using sklearn's `Pipeline` as follows:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pipe = Pipeline([("scaler", StandardScaler()),
                 ("regression", RidgeCV())])

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = pipe.predict(X_test)
```

From my understanding this first standardizes all training instances before passing it to RidgeCV. In RidgeCV, the data is split up (e.g. via k-fold CV) to find the best regularization (alpha) parameter values. Is this a case of data leakage, since alphas are determined based on held-out data that was standardized together with the fitted data? If so, how can this be avoided?

Comment: Your code doesn't correspond to your question, because in the code you seem to be using a train set for preprocessing and training and a test set for validation.

Comment: @Tim What I meant to ask is whether RidgeCV really finds the best alphas since the split of the training set into a training and validation set as part of RidgeCV might be subject to data leakage.

Comment: I still don't understand. What leakage?

Comment: @Tim Ok so the pipeline receives `X_train`. The scaler transforms `X_train` into `X_train_transformed`. For RidgeCV with a k-fold scheme, `X_train_transformed` is split up into two parts: `X_train_folds` and `X_valid_fold`. This will be used to find the best alphas based on fitting the regression line and minimizing the r2 with respect to the targets. Now, in my opinion `X_valid_fold` is not independent from `X_train_folds` because they were mutually standardized by the scaler. Does that make it more clear or am I missing something?

Comment: Why would this be a problem?

Comment: @Tim I would think for the same reason as why `X_train` and `X_test` should not be scaled together either. To avoid wrong estimates of the error. I believe that the same should hold when tuning the hyperparameters on a validation set but it seems that `Pipeline` doesn't consider this. Or do you think it's not an issue?

Comment: @flanders - I believe Pipeline *does* take this into account in the CV process. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075202/using-scaler-in-sklearn-pipeline-and-cross-validation